# Why does Document at a time scoring allow us to skip over parts of longer lists while doing intersection?

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

This is a information retrieval question. When we do document at a time scoring, why does DAAT allow us to skip over parts of longer lists. I am reading a research paper called Using Graphics Processors for High Perfomance IR Query Processing, in which they just mention the above property without any explanation. AN example will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Considering a "AND" query, for example:

```
"Gaga AND CD"
```

You can imagine that `Gaga` is much more rare than CD. In other words, the posting list (or inverted list as you will) of `Gaga` is much shorter than the one for `CD`.

Let's assume two small posting lists for the two words (I'm showing only the doc_ids, which are the objects of interest here):

```
Gaga -> [2, 10, 1023, 2030]
CD   -> [1, 2, 6, 8, 15, 32, 43, 52, 92, 115, 326, 401, 560, 564, ... , 1924, 2030, ...]
```

In Document-at-a-time retrieval, we iterate through posting lists in paralell looking for docs that match the query (in a AND query, just every doc that occurs in both posting lists).

In this type of retrieval, we can skip documents by knowing the most rare term (`Gaga`). That way we can use its posting list as a "pivot". 
The first doc_id to look for is `2`, than is `10`. Note that, we can skip all doc_ids between `2` and `10` in `CD` posting lists, because we know it won't match anything. Similarly, the next doc_id processed is `1023`. When processing `1023` we can skip at least 10 documents (from `15` to something after `564`), because we know it won't match anything.

The algorithm (for the AND query) is basically an array intersection. When you got a intersection you process it. Otherwise you keep skipping.

**UPDATE**: Many implementations use [Skip Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) to avoid doing comparisons while processing inverted lists. In the example above, the system could use the skip list to "jump" to the next position of `CD` inverted list that has a doc_id close to 10. That way it won't need to compare with `6` and `8`.

Comment: You mentioned that we can "skip all doc_ids between 2 and 10 in CD posting lists, because we know it won't match anything". However, in order to skip these intermediate doc IDs, we still need to compare 10 with 6 and 8.  Thus, we are not actually skipping things because we are incurring the comparison cost of comparing 10 with the elements in the inverted list of CD. Can you please clarify what you mean by skip and how does it save the computation cost?